# How to generate "n" div elements at particular times interval with javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I want to create a Time Ticker for my web page, for that I use HTML, Javascript and JSP: 
well my ticker is simple: with a java I develop a simple crawler to get content from websites, once I get it, I try to extract some content from the page and put it on div elements in my HTML page, I saw all the questions posted here about creating div elements but it is on a static way, I want to make generating elements at particular times interval (e.g. the feed Story Ticker oof facebook). This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="news" script="create()">
   <div id="section">
      <h4 id="titre"></h4>
      <p id="contenu"></p>
      <p id="authDate"></p>
      <a id="lien" href=" #">Voir...</a>
      <img src="#" alt="Une illustration" id="figure" />        
   </div> 
</div>
```

my goal is to generate "n" div elements that have `id="section"` in the div element with `id="news"` 
The script correspondant of the javascrit function `create()` is like that:

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
function create(){
   document.body.appendChild(iDiv);
   iDiv.id = 'section';
   iDiv.innerHTML = '<span class="msg">Hello world.</span>';
}
```

it creates a one div element so how can I create n div elements and control them

Comment: The question aside, you might not want to create multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: @TomNijs yes I want to create multiple div elements with same ID and with the same content of the div element

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, what -exactly- do you need help with? Is it the dynamic creation of HTML elements? Is it the timed interval at which a function is called? Please elaborate.

Comment: I want to create div elements on my page web (e.g. the Story Ticker feed of facebook), at each time there is a content facebook create the event, I appreciate your help

Comment: @TomNijs The function that I want to develop called at for exemple 3 minutes to create a dynamic div element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that is called every 180 seconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // Anything in here will be executed every 180 seconds (180 000 milliseconds)
    createDiv();
},180000);

// This function will add an empty div to your news element every 180 seconds
function createDiv() {
    var createdDiv = document.createElement("div");
    createdDiv.innerHTML = "TEST";
    document.getElementById("news").appendChild(createdDiv);
}
```

Comment: Iwould to Thank you @Tom Njis this really gonna help me, just where to put the script to make it run well sorry I'm not familiar with javascript

Comment: To call this function, simply create a <script></script> tag at the bottom of your body for example and paste my code in there. You will see it working every 3 minutes.

Comment: Thank you bro you are the best this is what i really want